# Laptop power supply unit compared to PC power supply unit

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power-consumption

PC power supplies are relatively huge compared to those used with laptops.

But why is this so when a laptop today can have an equal level of performance as a high end PC?

Are they both switching power supplies or is the laptop PSU something completely different?

Also, why is it that a laptop power supply does not need a cooling fan but a PC one does?

And is there some serious difference in electricity consumption that one should factor in when deciding on whether to buy a laptop or a PC?

Comment: A decent size laptop power supply is maybe around the 100W range while a decent size desktop power supply is probably closer to the 900w range. Also I don't know I've personally ever seen a desktop power supply below 200w, which is really small for a desktop, but still over twice as big as the average laptop's PSU. So yes, a laptop uses a lot less energy.

Comment: Nope, not at all. While there are laptops that *do* carry desktop or server grade hardware the typical laptop PSU probably *tops* out at 130W, though 65 or 90 watts is more typical. Your typical laptop PSU also probably only outputs *one* voltage that makes things simpler. 
Even a dual xeon based monster of a laptop *tops out* at 300W. The average *low end* PC power supply is 300W. 500W is more typical for a gaming rig, and you can go up to 1.5 Kw for a power supply. Don't forget that laptops also are designed with tighter thermal requirements and that is a constraint on performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laptops don't have an equal level of performance as a high end PC. Even high-end laptops generally use different CPUs, different memory, different GPUs, fewer drives, and so on. High-end laptops have larger power supplies, close to the size of desktop power supplies.